# Why does WP rename similar "term name"-slugs in separate taxonomies?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, slug, terms

I have several custom taxonomies and within two of those ( Company Categories and Photographer Categories ) I have a term that is similar. The Company Category called Boudoir and the Photographer category called Boudoir Photographers.

When I created the Boudoir Photographer term in the Photographer Categories it renamed the Boudoir term in the Company Categories to Boudoir Photography.

Why did this happen? The number of posts for either taxonomy term doe snot change, only its name and the slug.

Thanx in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are all in your `{wpdb->prefix}_terms` table and therefore need to be unique. Else you could only get them via ID.

Comment: But they are unique. "Boudoir" is not the same as "Boudoir Photographer". Unless the first word can't be the same. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Missunderstood you - thought you wanted to name both with the same slug. So: Hm... Wired. Are you sure your categories don't share the same slug or name? Please update your Q with every detail you can imagine.

Comment: No problem. I just figured it out. When I first created the Boudoir Photographer term, I simply named it Boudoir. So I deleted this term and created "Boudoir Photography." So it wasn't anything WP was doing - just me overlooking my own mistake. Thanx for your help!

Comment: N/P. Can happen to anybody. Please mark the A as solution so it doesn't appear under unanswered Qs. Thanks.